# Playing sound when tapped on item in ListView

Tags: java, android, audio

So I'm trying to play sound when a item, or row of ListView is pressed. I'm using this code:

```
listaMjeseci.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0){
                    MediaPlayer sijecanj = MediaPlayer.create(Mjeseci.this, R.raw.section1_mjeseci_sijecanj);
                    sijecanj.start();
                }
            }
        });
```

and getting null pointer exception. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you assigned the ListView using findViewById(int)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                        if (position == 0)
                       {
                    MediaPlayer sijecanj = MediaPlayer.create(Mjeseci.this, R.raw.section1_mjeseci_sijecanj);
                    sijecanj.start();
                }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What's the difference? The only difference I'm seeing here is that you don't have the `AdapterView.`. It would help the poster if you can elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Yeah that works like a charm. The difference is that Override is missing in his answer.. When I deleted it, sounds is playing like it is suposed to. Can you explain me why did Override caused this error?

Comment: @DaxHR `@Override` has not caused error . Error is because of `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` . Use `new OnItemClickListener()` , has you want a Item click Listener not a Adapter Click Listener. When you were using `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` no Adapter is associated with this Listener that's why you are getting null pointer. Hope you understand.